# Kohana ORM update, insert or delete to return number of affected rows

Tags: php, kohana

How can I get the number of affected rows after create, update or delete using ORM for Kohana?  I checked the main class but don't return that value...

If there any possible solution to do this, please let me know.  If it is possible not use the Query Builder, i prefer use only the ORM class.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you want to create/update/delete more than one record without QBuilder?

Comment: First of all, thank you for respond.  Well, actually, let's say that I want to Update my records with a particular condition (where) using ORM... for example if I want to disable all my users:

ORM::factory('User')->where('status', '=', 'disabled');

How do I know how many users was updated?

Comment: ORM always uses QBuilder and `Database_Result` object. Read this please: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/results. You need something like `$affected = ORM::factory('user')->where('status', '=', 'disabled')->...->execute();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to its [Cascading Filesystem](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/files#cascading-filesystem) it's very easy in Kohana to make some changes in system or module classes.

In your case you need to redefine methods of `ORM` module main class. Its file is located in `/modules/orm/classes/kohana/orm.php`.

Create new `ORM` module main class file in `/application/classes/orm.php` and redefine `create`, `update` and `delete` methods so these methods to return the number of affected rows.

For example new `update` method should end with this:

```
// Update a single record
$update_result = DB::update($this->_table_name)
    ->set($data)
    ->where($this->_primary_key, '=', $id)
    ->execute($this->_db);

if (isset($data[$this->_primary_key]))
{
    // Primary key was changed, reflect it
    $this->_primary_key_value = $data[$this->_primary_key];
}

// Object has been saved
$this->_saved = TRUE;

// All changes have been saved
$this->_changed = array();
$this->_original_values = $this->_object;

return $update_result;
```